# Efficient way to filter an Object Array on a specific property?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash

I have an array of objects with different properties and I need to filter the array in a way that a specific property is not duplicated.

For example:

```
var array:Array = [{foo:"a1", bar:"b1", baz:"c1"},
                   {foo:"a2", bar:"b2", baz:"c2"},
                   {foo:"a3", bar:"b1", baz:"c3"},
                   {foo:"a1", bar:"b4", baz:"c2"},
                   {foo:"a0", bar:"b3", baz:"c1"}];
```

Now suppose I want to filter the objects on the property `baz`. What is the most efficient way of filtering the array, so that no two elements have the same value for `baz` after the operation?

In my example, the result should only contain:

```
var result:Array = [{foo:"a1", bar:"b1", baz:"c1"},
                    {foo:"a2", bar:"b2", baz:"c2"},
                    {foo:"a3", bar:"b1", baz:"c3"}]
```

since the other objects would have duplicate entries for the `baz` property.

The order of the result array is not important, neither is which object of those with identical values for `baz` makes it into the result array.

---

#### Update:

The object array is used as a dataprovider to populate a `s:Datagrid` with information about chatrooms. The objects in the array carry related information (like the room's ID on the server and some other config settings).

The `baz` property I used in my example is actually the ID of the language the chat room is configured to use and I want to create a `s:DropDownList` with which I can filter the `Datagrid` for individual languages (e.g. show all rooms that use "German").

It is very likely to have many objects with the same language ID, but I only want each language Id to show up once in the `DropDownList`.

I need to extract that information from the `Datagrids's` dataprovider (the source array) and cannot retrieve my languages directly since the `DropDownList` is part of a generic `DatagridHeaderRenderer` that is used in many different `Datagrids` with different data.

Comment: @wvxvw: It should really create a copy since the source array must not be modified. I'll add the use case with some more info to the question. The source array is not sorted by the property it should be filtered by, and the chance of repetition of identical values for `baz` is high.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the surface of it looks like it should work. Using Array.filter is usually about twice the time of doing the same thing in a loop.

I'd argue that' Dom's `removeDupes` function doesn't do exactly what's required, although it might be a more generic approach (if, for example, the `===` isn't a good comparison function, then this gives you a way of extending it.) But using `hasOwnPropery` is a big no-no. You should never touch it - that function only exists for ES compatibility. It is evil otherwise - both a potential security hole (as it is defined on `Object.prototype` and thus is easy to override for the foreign code) and is slow (for the same reason - the lookup of the functions defined on prototype is slower then those defined in a class).

```
    public function Test()
    {
        super();
        var array:Array = [{foo:"a1", bar:"b1", baz:"c1"},
            {foo:"a2", bar:"b2", baz:"c2"},
            {foo:"a3", bar:"b1", baz:"c3"},
            {foo:"a1", bar:"b4", baz:"c2"},
            {foo:"a0", bar:"b3", baz:"c1"}];
        this.removeDuplicates(array, "baz").map(this.objectTracer);
        // { foo : a3, baz : c3, bar : b1 }
        // { foo : a1, baz : c2, bar : b4 }
        // { foo : a0, baz : c1, bar : b3 }
    }

    private function objectTracer(object:Object, index:int, all:Array):void
    {
        var result:String = "";
        for (var p:String in object)
            result += ", " + p + " : " + object[p];
        if (result) result = result.substr(2);
        trace("{ " + result + " }");
    }

    private function removeDuplicates(array:Array, on:String):Array
    {
        var result:Array = array.concat();
        // note that since we use `Dictionary' the 
        // the comparison between objects is the same as `==='
        // if all values are strings, you can use `Object' to
        // save some space.
        var hash:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
        var temp:Object;

        for (var i:int, j:int = result.length - 1; j >= i; j--)
        {
            temp = result[j][on];
            if (temp in hash)
            {
                result[j] = result[i];
                j++; i++;
            }
            else hash[temp] = true;
        }
        // note that we could `shift()` until we get to `i'
        // but when we do it, we actually reallocate the array every time
        // so `slice()' must, in theory, be more efficient
        return result.slice(i);
    }
```

Comment: Some of the stuff you say seems odd to me... hasOwnProperty() is a security hole?  Really?  There are some cases, like when searching  XML, when that method is really helpful.  Also, Array.filter() is slower than a loop?  Last time I actually checked, it was faster than using a loop.  Moreover, that is like the whole point of those native methods, right?  I will Google this on my own, but if you are citing a specific source, I would really like to check it out.

Comment: With the array native functions I did some performance tests.  But, based on your feedback, I will re-test them next time I need to optimize.  I may have had an edge case where using the native function was faster than the older logic I replaced it with.  I still don't see what the security issue is with hasOwnProperty() but I am not knowledgeable about security in general.  The details you gave me will help me search for more information, though, so thanks.

Comment: By the way, I still can't find anything online discussing the problem.  Searching "as3 hasownproperty security hole" actually brings up this thread. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
private var array:Array = [{foo:"a1", bar:"b1", baz:"c1"},
               {foo:"a2", bar:"b2", baz:"c2"},
               {foo:"a3", bar:"b1", baz:"c3"},
               {foo:"a1", bar:"b4", baz:"c2"},
               {foo:"a0", bar:"b3", baz:"c1"}];

private var filteredArray:Array;
private var keys:Object = {};

private function filterArray():void{
    filteredArray = arr.filter(removeDupes);
}

private function removeDupes(item:Object, idx:uint, arr:Array):Boolean {
    if (keys.hasOwnProperty(item.baz)){
        return false;
    } else {
        keys[item.baz] = item;
        return true;
    }
}

private function resetFilter():void{
    filteredArray = new Array();
    keys = {};
}
```

Modified from multiple sources but primarily: http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/08/05/removing-duplicate-items-from-an-array-using-the-arrayfilter-method/

Or you could just use an arrayCollection and its built-in filterFunction. See: http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Using_the_to_ArrayCollection_s_filterFunction-5441.html